# Docker: how to route path to port?

Tags: docker, port

I am running 2 applications using separate Docker containers on the same server.
The **first** application uses the port 8000. Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 8000
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
command: uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
ports:
  - "8000:8000"
```

The **second** application uses the port 8001. Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 8001
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
command: uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001
ports:
  - "8001:8001"
```

I have created DNS type A record:

```
api.mydomain.com to 123.123.123.123
```

**api.mydomain.com:8000** and **api.mydomain.com:8001** are both functioning. I want to route url path to port. For example:

```
api.mydomain.com/appone/ to api.mydomain.com:8000
api.mydomain.com/apptwo/ to api.mydomain.com:8001
```

Is it possible to do this using Docker? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Inspecting the path happens on layer 7, dockers routing happens on layer 4. It does not care about the application protocol, such as HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this using Docker?

Directly no, indirectly yes. Docker runs applications.

> how can I do it?

You can run a proxy HTTP server that forwards domains to specific ports. Nginx and Apache are the most popular HTTP servers. There is also Fabio proxy.

You can run that server inside docker.